# magento2 customer online grid - missed field: IP, Last URL, etc

Tags: magento2

How I can return in Magento 2 (version 2.0.0) some fields for customer online grid such as IP, Last URL, etc. ?

There are only 6 columns available in the columns menu:

[image: Magento 2.0.0 grid]

In Magento 2 beta version this fields were available:

[image: Magento 2-beta grid]

Comment: In magento 2 2.0.0 the  Mage_Log extension was deleted... But perhaps developers transferred this functionality to other extensions and users should enable it in the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer:

No, you cant, and you should not even try. The standard solution as of today is to use a 3th party service/software like google analytics or piwik.

more explanation:
The internal module responsible for this was removed, as it was not used in most cases, but had a big impact on performance.
Especially the "last url" is a very expensive feature, which requires a database write on each and every request of a customer. This are expensive, add 100-300ms to every request of the user, and use IO resources which are important for the order process and can in a worst case scenario slow the whole order process down, if you have a lot of customers online at the same time.
The last IP is maybe still possible to get from the last login entry. But I am not sure what magento stores related to this.

Also notable, there are countries where you are not allowed to store the full IP of users.